# .htaccess Shorten URL with HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

My apologies from the start as this has probably been answered in some way, and believe me I've tried all the "solutions" however I'm not good at .htaccess, and in a need of a quick help if I may ask.

What is bugging me that I managed to finally put the HTTPS www force on my domain to work, however I've ran into an issue where I do not want my url to be fully shown of my subdirectories,

For instance www.example.com/pages/link.html, 
I want to be shown as www.example.com/link.html

Among other directories like .../img/, or .../sub_admin/

Current Code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

As well what I recently tried to add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have tried this already. Add condition as required.

```
RewriteRule ^pages/link.html?$ http://example.com/link.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and yes I have already tried it, I need for all the /pages/ sites to be like that, so there must be a way to make all of the pages remove the /pages/ without writing every single page in the .htaccess

Comment: RewriteRule ^/pages/(.+) http ://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]